# Multithreading, memory order and function calls before new thread excecution

Tags: multithreading

For example, let's say we allocate a dynamic object `A` and call it's constructor. After that we create/run a new thread and pass the reference/pointer of `A` to this thread.

Is it guaranteed that the new thread sees object `A` as allocated and also constructed? Is there any reference to the answer?

Comment: What language / technology do you use? Do you have a code sample which illustrated what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: ...In some languages, using some libraries, the answer is yes, the new thread is guaranteed to see object `A` in a fully constructed state. Other languages and other libraries might require that you do something extra (e.g., like use a mutex lock) before that behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: @SolomonSlow what is the situation for c/c++ ? can you give me examples of languages that require a mutex lock for construction?

Comment: I have written multi-threaded code, and I have written C++ code, but I have not ever written multi-threaded C++.  I suspect the answer will depend on which version of the C++ language spec you ask about. Older versions were not thread-aware: You used `pthreads` or an OS-specific library, and you got implementation-defined behavior. The newest version, I _think_, has complete rules about which thread can see which variable update, and when—rules which are only valid if you use `std::...` library calls to create and manage threads—but I don't know any more about it than that.